# Lightmapper artifacts

Tags: unity, blender, uv-mapping, lightmap, import

I really don't understand why this is creating these kinds of artifacts. I'm starting to think something is wrong with Unity.

[image]

There are clearly no overlapping faces on the Model. There is enough of a margin to remove all chances of bleed. Yes the lid is a seperate object but any UV's of the lid and it's box are not overlapping. Thix odd pixelation occurs no matter the quality. It happened all the time sofar here and there and it forced me to replace a few objects in older projects. No idea what causes it. Really sick and tired of this.

### Edit:

*when I rotate the crate by 90 degrees the artifacts appear on the adjacent side of the cube. From the perspective of the camera it would be the same side. So clearly it's not the UV's or anything.*

[image]

### Lightmap settings

[image]

### Object Import settings

[image]